# Excel functions don't work with macro

Tags: vb.net, excel

So I got this macro to load stuff from another worksheet:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "http://DOMAIN/csdav/nodes/5865160/Projektoffertliste.xls"
 ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
 ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

and if I try using simple fuctions like =VALUE or =IF it just won't work and it says #VALUE as error code.

```
=DATEVALUE('http://DOMAIN/csdav/nodes/5865160/[Projektoffertliste.xls]Projektoffertliste'!B2)
```

Thats one usage example, i tried this too with =VALE because I first thought it was a DATEVALUE problem. the http://.... data getting does work but i can't use it with functions.

Comment: Could you add an example of what you are using the =VALUE or =IF?

Comment: Yeah got that covered

Comment: Try taking out the equals sign that you have inside of the DATEVALUE function.

Comment: Still doesn't work